# Differential equation $y'(t) + \frac{1}{t-g(t)}y(t) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, expected-value

Consider the following differential equation on $[0,+\infty)$

$$y'(t) + \frac{1}{t-g(t)}y(t) = \frac{1}{t-g(t)} \text{ and } y(0)=0. \qquad(1)$$

First the constant function equal to $1$ is a solution and one only needs to study the following differential equation on $[0,+\infty)$

$$y'(t) + \frac{1}{t-g(t)}y(t) = 0.$$

Suppose $g(t) = (1-a)\ln(1+t)-a$, where $0<a<1$.

Is there an explicit formula for the solutions of this equations ?
If not, what can be said, even numerically ?

My ultimate goal is to compute the expectation of a random variable with CDF a solution of $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If
$y'+fy=0$ then
$y'/y=-f$ so
$(\ln y)'=-f$ so
$\ln y =-\int f +c$ and
$y = e^{-\int f +c}
=Ce^{-\int f}
$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I forgot to precise it but I know the general solution of such a differential equation.